# Running compiled lisp program with clisp-2.49 on OS X

Tags: common-lisp, clisp

I have just started out programming in Common Lisp using GNU clisp-2.49 (compiled from source) as my implementation on OS X 10.10 Yosemite. I've written a simple "Hello World" program as follows:

```
(EXT:SAVEINITMEM "test"
  :INIT-FUNCTION 'main
  :EXECUTABLE t)
(defun main ()
  (format t "Hello World!")
  (EXT:EXIT))
```

When I run:

```
$ clisp test.lisp
$ ./test
```

I get the error:

```
module 'syscalls' requires package OS.
```

Please help, I'm totally clueless :)

Comment: Usually you load and compile your code, then write image. You write image before makeing your interpreted main function. Thus when running you should get an error about `main` being undefined since you have saved the image of a virgin clisp. I almost never do this. If you just add `(main)` to the bottom and remove the `EXT` stuff you run it with the first command you do. You can also add a shebang and make it executable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in clisp.
Please report it on [SF](https://sourceforge.net/p/clisp/bugs/).
Note that this works as it should on Ubuntu with the vanilla distribution.

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have created [ticket #673](http://www.sourceforge.net/p/clisp/bugs/673)

Comment: Any progress on this? Issue persists on 10.15 (Catalina)